# SSH in local network while hosting same network

Tags: ssh, networking, openssh, wifi-hotspot

I have the following setup:

Computer A has a Wifi-USB adapter (and is a robot, so it doesn't need real internet access). It's running Ubuntu 14.04.
Computer B is my Laptop running Ubuntu 14.04 also.

What I have done is setup a local Wifi hotspot on Computer B using [this](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/09/3-ways-create-wifi-hotspot-ubuntu/) guide. It has an ethernet cable connected to it, which gives it access to the "outside". It works fine, computer A can join the network and I can ping computer A from Computer B and the other way around.

However, I cannot ssh from Computer B to Computer A, I always get the following error.

```
ssh youbot@ComputerA.local
ssh: connect to host ComputerA.local port 22: Connection refused
```

To my understanding I do not need to install openssh-server on Computer A, since I am only trying to ssh while in the same network. (Is this correct?)

If I run

```
sudo iptables -L
```

I get the follwong output:
Computer B:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootps
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:bootps
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:domain

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             10.42.0.0/24         state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  10.42.0.0/24         anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Computer A:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target        prot opt source                destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target        prot opt source                destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target        prot opt source                destination
```

I have ufw disabled on both computers. Since I am really not a ssh expert, can anybody tell me what I can do to fix this?

If further information is needed, I'd be glad to provide it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, apparently I do need openssh-server on Computer A, even though I am in the same network. I read that wrong somewhere else then.

Comment: Yes. The ssh server allows the machine to accept incoming connections, which is what you're trying to do.